# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't detect USB phone

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount, phone, detect

Ubuntu 14.04, 13.10, 13.04, 12.10 doesn't detect and doesn't mount my USB attached phone. So I cannot transfer files between my laptop and the phone's micro SD card.

Windows 8, and Ubuntu 12.04 does detect and mount the phone's SD card. I tried Ubuntu 14.04, and I can say, that it is the loveliest operating system I have ever used. But unfortunately it doesn't detect my phone's SD card, so I had to go back to Ubuntu 12.04 which is still a good OS, but not as smooth as Ubuntu 14.04.

By the way:  It does detect iphone and other android smart phones. (My phone is not an Android smart phone.) Just a simple Allview m7 Start dual sim phone.
Somewhere I read that the issue might be USB power related....

Any ideas about what has been changed since Ubuntu 12.04?
Any ideas how to fix this issue? I have already tried almost everything

Comment: Need more info on what you are trying to do and how the phone does that. If you just need data off an SD card, how does the phone supply this? Tried an SD card reader? Tried Bluetooth?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your reply.
Well When I connect my phone, the phone gives me the following options for USB CONFIG: 1. Mass storage 2. COM port. I generally use option 1 for copying data from the SD card.
Now it is working perfectly, because I downgraded from 14.04 to 12.04. But my laptop (Lenovo B590)doesn't work as well with 12.04 as with 14.04.

I also tried 14.04 on another laptop. But the problem persists. Now I am sure that, something might have been changed after Ubuntu 12.04. That is the last version that detects my phone. I tried all the newer versions without success.

Comment: I have found this: Is it possible, that 14.04 cannot handle USB- power properly?
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150193/ubuntu-14-04-lts-usb-3-0-low-output-or-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Allview m7 Start doesn't sound so mainstream (no offense), meaning that the VendorID might be necessary to allow it to connect via USB. Weird stuff, but similar to what I experienced with different phones (Ubuntu phones, but the problem was with the PC. It could very well be that your problem is the same, and can pretty easily be fixed. Open up a terminal on your pc, and run:

```
lsusb
```

The lsusb command lists all usb devices. this is to get the vendorID from your phone. Output should look something like this: (if you don't know which device it is, unplug, run lsusb, then plug in, run lsusb again. Probably there is no name after the ID code if it is unidentifiable)

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:021e Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
```

The 4 character string after ID is the vendorID. This needs to be listed in ~/.android/adb_usb.ini. Because this is hexidecimal, it has to be prefixed with "0x":

```
0x2a45
```

If the file or directory is not present, (I'm not sure and can't really test now, please comment on that!) the above may not help without installing android-tools first:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth a shot, I have a Xaiomi phone and it has to be plugged into a USB port, then I restart ubuntu (restart PC) and then it shows up. Trying by just plugging in and using a file explorer doesnt work.

Not exactly perfect but a good enough work around.